# Extension on Array where Element is generic not compiling

Tags: swift

I'm wondering why this compiles

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    func newTest() {
        let array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
        let j = Array(array.joined())
        let f = array.flatMap{$0}
    }
}
```

But this does not compile

```
struct Test<T> {}

extension Array where Element == Test<Int> {
    func newTestGeneric() {
        let array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
        let j = Array(array.joined())
        let f = array.flatMap{$0}
    }
}
```

On this line
`let j = Array(array.joined())`

I get an error:
`Ambiguous reference to member 'joined()'`

Comment: You have to write `let j = Array<Int>(array.joined())`

Comment: Aren't you saying that the elements in the array are of the type Test<Int> in the second example and Test does not conform to `Sequence` which is required. See [joined](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945737-joined)

Comment: The problem is that  the compiler treats `Array(...)` as `Array<Element>(...)`, and in the second case `Element != Int`. – That is a bug, as explained in the linked-to Q&A.